# React native: The "Google Chrome" application cannot be started

Tags: google-chrome, react-native

Today i've attempted to start dev environment, as usual and got this alert:

[image]

Nothing seems to be changed. One thing I've noticed is that chrome started asking for update today. The error has shown up before i've restarted chrome and updated it. But still, i assume, there were some critical changes introduced and begun breaking things once again. Anyone got/solved it already?

OS X 10.11.6
Chrome 57.0.2987.133

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a Parallels issue, do you have Chrome installed on a Windows VM on your Mac using Parallels?

If so, removing Chrome from Windows to see if the problem still persists might be the first test.

My theory is that RN is trying to launch Chrome but it's locating the one inside of the VM instead of the app on OSX.